# Javascript: how to combine two adjacent elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know how to combine two or more adjacent elements of an array.

For example, I have an array arr = `['a','bb','ccc','d','e','f','g','hhhhhhhh']` and I want to concatenate some elements to make it `['a','bb', 'ccc', 'defg','hhhhhhhh']`.  Specifically, I want to do the following: if an element's length is less than its index plus one, I want to concatenate it with the element that follows, eliminating the element that follows.  (I.e., for this example, because `arr[3].length` <= 3+1, it gets concatenated with the elements that follow it until `arr[3].length == 3+1`.)  I'll be executing this from inside a loop, and working from left to right in the array.

Is there any easy way to do this in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just turn your English into JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) { // I want to concatenate the middle elements
    while (array[i].length <= i && typeof array[i + 1]!='undefined' ) { //if an element's length is less than or equal to its index
        array[i] += array[i + 1]; //I want to concatenate it with the element that follows
        array.splice(i + 1, 1); //eliminating the element that follows
    }
}
```

See it in action:

```js
var array = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'hhhhhhhh'];
for (var i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
 while (array[i].length <= i && typeof array[i + 1]!='undefined' ) {
  array[i] += array[i + 1];
  array.splice(i + 1, 1);
 }
}
alert(array.join(', '));
```

Comment: It should be less or equal than the index, no? The `if` statement checks for that.

Comment: There's no `would be` in my code - simply run it and you'll get what the OP asked for. `Run code snippet`

Comment: How come? I get `['a','bb', 'ccdd','eeeee']`.

Comment: Ah, okay... But it's fine, isn't it? `bb` gets skipped because 2>1 and `c` gets concatted to `d`.

Comment: Question is whether we go zero-based or one-based. My code is zero-based (OP didn't specify). And yes, it should go into loop for another concat runs, but I'm not going to write the whole thing, just address the issue since OP didn't show any effort (I probably already did too much).

Comment: Thanks Shomz, I got everything except the `array.splice(i+1, 1)`; that's the the helpful bit I was looking for which eliminates the following element. :)

Comment: I just hoped you would create some recursive function in the speed of light you answered this question first time :) thank you for your time

Comment: Haha, sorry, my warp drive needed refueling. Seriously: I was thinking about not posting the answer because I thought I was giving away too much. :) Sorry I didn't get what you were saying from the first comment.

Comment: How would you accomplish with adjacent objects in an array of objects, and when they are merged the properties of the second object are added to the first?

Comment: @zero_cool In a similar way, but instead of merging full array elements, you'd iterate through the object's properties and merge them instead.